Regular expression to capture the first 4 Numbers from a string
Was playing around with regex to learn it better and wondering if we can write regex to match something like the following use case below
Example String: 1_234_3456_345
Expected result: I want to match just the first 4 Numbers from this string using regex. Meaning just 1234 ignoring the underscore in between.
Another Example: 123_7689_54A
Expected Result: 1237 (Only the first 4 Numbers from the string should be matched, ignoring the chars in between them)
I tried out with something like this:
/\d.*?\d.*?\d.*?\d/

But in the above examples: (first one) and in the second one 123_7 I want it to omit the _ in between.
What do I do? Is this possible in the first place?

With regex you cannot have a single match that is not a substring of the input.

What about 1__234 (with two underscores), or 1e234 (with a different character than underscore) or 1_2_3_4?

We could avoid the regex using str.each_char.lazy.filter_map {|e| Integer(e, exception: false) }.first(4).join. This also solves @trincot's concerns.

A regex match is always a substring of the string being matched against, so it is impossible for a match to "ignore" certain substrings within the matching substring.
You can instead enclose each of the 4 digits in a capture group so that you can join the captured digits into a string:
puts /(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)/.match("1_234_3456_345").captures.join

This outputs:
1234

Demo: https://ideone.com/UD7Q2g

Alternative using regex and substring:
string = "1_234_3456_345"
result = string.gsub(/\D/, '')[0, 4]
puts result

Try this:
(?:\d|_(?=\d)){4}

Explanation short:
Digit or underscores+digit four times.
Explanation long:
(?: ... ) is a non-capturing group.
\d matches any digit.
| is the alternation operator, meaning "or".
_(?=\d) matches an underscore only if it's followed by a digit (using a positive lookahead assertion).
{4} quantifier specifies that the preceding group should match exactly four times.

Apologies if I have portrayed my question wrongly. But I did not want to match the underscores at all. just the first 4 Numbers alone. is that possible ?

For Example: 1_234_3456_345
in this case I only want to match the first 4 Numbers (digits) ignoring any special characters in between them

You can't get this as a result directly. You need to remove the _ programmatically.

You could remove all characters but numbers from the string and create a substring of it. Look at my updated answer.

Good idea, isn't it! You wrote in headline "without regex", it uses regex doesn't it?

Oh, you are right. That's what happens if one (me) is doing something a little bit to quickly! Thank you!
